# how to call method in login page

Tags: android

i'm currently trying to make a validation for a login page, which is to validate whether the account is in my database or not, i'm to call the method of invokelogin(), but it seems  but i don't know how to call the method, need some help with it.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Activity_Login extends Activity{

   private Button btnSignIn;

   String username;
   String pass;

   public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

   EditText txtUser;
   EditText Pass;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchActivity3();
        }
    });
}

public void launchActivity3() {

    txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);

    if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "UserName must Be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (Pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity_Login.this, "Password must be Filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        invokeLogin();
    }
        Intent intent_SignIn = new Intent(Activity_Login.this, Activity_Drawer2.class);
        startActivity(intent_SignIn);
}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = txtUser.getText().toString();
    pass = Pass.getText().toString();

    login(username,pass);
}

private void login (final String username, String pass){

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity_Login.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String uname = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.10.1.11/login.php");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Login.this, Activity_Drawer2.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, pass);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **txtUser** and **Pass**  to  invokeLogin();

so it look like `invokeLogin(txtUser,Pass);`

Then your `invokeLogin` method

```
public void invokeLogin(String username, String pass){
    login(username,pass);
}
```

Comment: there seems to an error of java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference at "class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>", and " String s = result.trim();", do you know why?

Comment: @User9124 check what is returned from doInBackground. It might be null

Comment: what should i return?